# Match 1st dataframe's column 'items' with 2nd dataframe's columns, if match then display match value in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

> I have tried this below code, values matched but result stored under same column i.e, "items" :

'''

```
for ticker in tickers:
 asset = str(int(df['asset'].values[0]))
 ...
 match = [ticker, asset, debt, debtc]
 def checkIfValuesExists1(df, ticker):
  for ele in ticker:
   if ele in df['items'].values:
    out[ele] = match      
   return out
 out = checkIfValuesExists1(df, match)
```

'''

| ticker | items |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 |
| MSFT | 7778 |
| GOOGL | 7654 |

| ticker | asset | debt | debtc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 | 2424 | 4567 |
| MSFT | 7708 | 7778 | 8579 |
| GOOGL | 7954 | 2342 | 7654 |

| ticker | asset | debt | debtc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 |  |  |
| MSFT |  | 7778 |  |
| GOOGL |  |  | 7654 |

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the `items` column to the all other three columns in `df2` based on `ticker` column

```py
m = df2.set_index('ticker').eq(df1.set_index('ticker')['items'], axis=0)
```

```
print(m)

        asset   debt  debtc
ticker
AAPL     True  False  False
MSFT    False   True  False
GOOGL   False  False   True
```

Then use `where` to turn the `False` part to `NaN`

```py
df_ = df2.set_index('ticker').where(m, np.nan).astype('Int64').reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

  ticker  asset  debt  debtc
0   AAPL   4564  <NA>   <NA>
1   MSFT   <NA>  7778   <NA>
2  GOOGL   <NA>  <NA>   7654
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
(df2.melt(value_name = 'items').merge(df1).
      pivot('ticker', 'variable').reset_index())
 
         ticker items            
variable        asset  debt debtc
0          AAPL  4564   NaN   NaN
1         GOOGL   NaN   NaN  7654
2          MSFT   NaN  7778   NaN
```